# How to remove double quotes on specific column from CSV file using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-1.0

```
"ID","Full Name","Age"

"1","Jone Micale","25"
```

Here a sample from a CSV file that I created, and now I want to remove double quotes from only the `ID` and `Age` column value.

I tried different ways but I don't want to create a new file out of it. I just want to update the file with changes using *PowerShell v1*.

Comment: Could you please explain the reasoning to do this? I'm sure there is a perfectly good explanation, but the above is a perfectly "valid" csv (though csv isn't terribly standardized, of course, generally wrapping columns in quotation characters is accepted). Is it to get a smaller file or is it for importing the data, and if so why are you having trouble importing the data just because of the quotation characters?

Comment: The above example was sample of how my csv file looks like. There are number of fields available out of them i just wanted to remove double quotes on specific fields like ID and Age. I don't want to remove double quotes on Full Name field. This csv I am going to use in another DQM activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export-Csv` will always put all fields in double quotes, so you have to remove the undesired quotes the hard way. Something like this might work:

```
$csv = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'
(Get-Content $csv) -replace '^"(.*?)",(.*?),"(.*?)"$', '$1,$2,$3' |
    Set-Content $csv
```

Regular expression breakdown:

- `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of a string respectively (`Get-Content` returns an array with the lines from the file).
- `"(.*?)"` matches text between two double quotes and captures the match (without the double quotes) in a group.
- `,(.*?),` matches text between two commas and captures the match (including double quotes) in a group.
- `$1,$2,$3` replaces a matching string with the comma-separated first, second and third group from the match.

Comment: Hey thanx Ansgar....great solution. As I am new for PowerShell, can you elaborate this logic for me please. Thanx in Advance

Comment: That means how may fields i have in my CSV, I have to insert that much "(.*?)" and $4.... some number in script ?

Comment: And in above logic where actually you are saying power-shell to remove double quotes ? Can you please tell me.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, this logic not working on big size or content file data. :( I tried it on big size file but it only removes header double quotes. Please tell me solution on it.

Comment: @ppatil The above is not a generic solution. In its current form it removes double quotes from the first and last field of a CSV with 3 fields. If your input data looks differently, you'd need to adjust the pattern accordingly.