# Powershell script to remove double quotes from CSV unless comma exists inside double quotes

Tags: regex, powershell, csv

I have a .csv in the following file format:

```
In: "bob","1234 Main St, New York, NY","cool guy"
```

I am looking to remove double quotes that don't have a comma inside:

```
Out: bob,"1234 Main St, New York, Ny",cool guy
```

Is there a way to do this in Powershell?

I have checked:

1. [How to remove double quotes on specific column from CSV file using Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902966/how-to-remove-double-quotes-on-specific-column-from-csv-file-using-powershell-sc)
2. http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/11/02/remove-unwanted-quotation-marks-from-csv-files-by-using-powershell.aspx
3. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f6b610b6-bfb2-4140-9529-e61ad30b8927/how-to-export-csv-without-doublequote?forum=winserverpowershell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adapting the code from ["How to remove double quotes on specific column from CSV file using Powershell script"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21902966/how-to-remove-double-quotes-on-specific-column-from-csv-file-using-powershell-sc):

```
$csv = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'
(Get-Content $csv) -replace '(?m)"([^,]*?)"(?=,|$)', '$1' |
    Set-Content $csv
```

The regex `(?m)"([^,]*?)"(?=,|$)` is matching any `" + 0 or more non-commas + "` *before* a comma or end of line (achieved with a positive look-ahead and a multiline option `(?m)` that forces `$` to match a newline, not just the end of string).

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fX6jY5/4)

Comment: Thanks for all your help, Wiktor - I've cleaned up my previous comments. Final thought: You can put the `(?m)` to good use if you use `Get-Content -Raw` (PSv3+) to read the entire file into a single string, which will also speed up things. However, to avoid an extra trailing newline, the output then has to be written with `Set-Content -NoNewline` - which is PSv5+: `(Get-Content -Raw $csv) -replace '(?m)"([^,]*?)"(?=,|$)', '$1' | Set-Content -NoNewline $csv`

Comment: Agree with mklement0, without `-Raw` the purpose of `(?m)` is defeated mind as well not be in the regex.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon It is a 2015 post when I knew very little of Powershell. The `(?m)` containing regex is still good since it can be tested in any .NET compliant regex online tester.

Comment: I wasn't critiquing the answer, I'm saying that future readers would benefit by seeing `-Raw` in your `Get-Content` statement. In PowerShell `-replace` can evaluate an array of strings so the regex works both ways with and without `-Raw` but `(?m)` is useful only if `-Raw` is there, so essentially what mklement0 pointed out in his comment

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: In PowerShell [Core] v7+, a much simpler solution is possible: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60086908/45375).

---

The existing answers work well with the sample input:

- [Wiktor Stribiżew's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248160/45375), which identifies double-quoted fields that do not contain `,` using a regex, loads the entire input file into memory first, which enables replacing the input file with the results in a single pipeline.
  While this is convenient - and faster than row-by-row processing - the caveat is that it may not be an option for large input files.
- [markg's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30247250/45375), which splits rows into fields by `"` chars., is an alternative for large input files, because it uses the pipeline to process the input rows one by one.
  (As a consequence, the input file cannot be directly updated with the result.)

If we ***generalize* the OP's requirement to also handle fields with *embedded `"` chars.***, we need a different approach:

The following fields must then retain their enclosing double quotes:

- (of necessity) double-quoted fields with embedded `,` chars.; e.g.,
  `"1234 Main St, New York, NY"`
- (of necessity) double-quoted fields with embedded `"` chars., which, per [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) must be escaped as `""`, i.e., *doubled*; e.g.,
  `"Nat ""King"" Cole"`

<sup>Note:</sup>

- We are *not* dealing with fields that may contain embedded *line breaks*, as that would require a fundamentally different approach, because self-contained line-by-line processing is then no longer possible.
- Tip of the hat to [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew), who came up with the regex to robustly match a double-quoted field with an arbitrary number of embedded double quotes, escaped as `""`: `"([^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*)"`

```
# Create sample CSV file with double-quoted fields that contain
# just ',', just embedded double quotes ('""'), and both.
@'
bob,"1234 Main St, New York, NY","cool guy"
nat,"Nat ""King"" Cole Lane","cool singer"
nat2,"Nat ""King"" Cole Lane, NY","cool singer"
'@ | Set-Content ./test.csv

Get-Content ./test.csv | ForEach-Object {
  # Match all double-quoted fields on the line, and replace those that 
  # contain neither commas nor embedded double quotes with just their content,
  # i.e., with enclosing double quotes removed.
  ([regex] '"([^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*)"').Replace($_, { param($match)
    $fieldContent = $match.Groups[1]
    if ($fieldContent -match '[,"]') { $match } else { $fieldContent }
  })
}
```

This yields:

```
bob,"1234 Main St, New York, NY",cool guy
nat,"Nat ""King"" Cole Lane",cool singer
nat2,"Nat ""King"" Cole Lane, NY",cool singer
```

**Updating the input file**:

As in markg's answer, due to line-by-line processing, you cannot directly update the input file with the output in the same pipeline.
To update the iput file later, use a temporary output file and then replace the input file with it (`...` represents the `Get-Content` pipeline from above, only with `$csvFile` instead of `./test.csv`):

```
$csvfile = 'c:\path\to\some.csv'
$tmpFile = $env:TEMP\tmp.$PID.csv
... | Set-Content $tmpFile
if ($?) { Move-Item -Force $tmpFile $csvFile }
```

Note that `Set-Content` uses your system's single-byte, extended-ASCII character encoding by default (even though the [help topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) [falsely states ASCII](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3248)).

Using the `-Encoding` parameter allows you specify a different encoding, but note that UTF-16LE, which is the default for `Out-File` / `>`, causes the CSV file not to be recognized properly by Excel, for instance.

Answer (score 2):

In **PowerShell [Core] v7+**, you can now use `-UseQuotes AsNeeded` with `ConvertTo-Csv` and `Export-Csv`, which greatly simplifies the approach:

```
@'
Name,Address,Comment
"bob","1234 Main St, New York, NY","cool guy"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | 
       ConvertTo-Csv -UseQuotes AsNeeded # use Export-Csv to save to a file.
```

The above yields the following, showing that only the field with the embedded `,` was double-quoted:

```
Name,Address,Comment
bob,"1234 Main St, New York, NY",cool guy
```

---

See the [`Export-Csv` v7+ docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Export-Csv):

- `-UseQuotes` accepts `AsNeeded`, `Always`, and `Newer`
- Seperately, there's also `-QuoteFields`, which accepts an *array of column (property) names* to which quoting should (selectively be applied).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what the rest of your script looks like. Try something along these lines though

```
(("bob","1234 Main St, New York, NY","cool guy") -split '"' | 
  ForEach-Object {IF ($_ -match ",") {'"' + $_ + '"' } ELSE {$_}}) -join ","
```