# How to sort TextBox input value to a output file with a delimiter?

Tags: powershell

As misleading as the title maybe I hope I can explain it thoroughly.

I have a PS form, with 5 different TextBoxes:
1 TextBox for FirstName
1 TextBox for LastName
1 TextBox for LoginName
1 TextBox for PhoneWork
1 TextBox for Delimiter

let's say I input this for example:
Donald as FirstName
Duck as LastName
DuckyDonald as LoginName
123456789 as PhoneWork
; as Delimiter

I then have this button, called $createbutton, and when it is pressed this happens:

```
$createbutton.Add_Click({

    $first = $firstname.Text
    $last = $lastname.Text
    $login = $loginname.Text
    $phone = $phonework.Text
    $d = $delimiter.Text

    $txt | Set-Content 'users.txt'

$first+$d+$last+$d+$login+$d+$phone | Add-Content 'users.txt'

})
```

So when I open my users.txt file I'll have this:
Donald;Duck;DuckyDonald;123456789

So, my form "works" without issues, but only when I create one user at a time. Now what I would like is to be able to input multiple FirstName,LastName,LoginName,Phonework and when I press the button it will automatically sort out the different values depending on which position they're at.

So let's say I enter this information:
Donald,Mickey,Goofy as FirstName
Duck,Mouse,Goof as LastName
DuckyDonald,MousyMick,GoofDaGoof as LoginName
123,456,789 as PhoneWork
; as Delimiter

I would like it to paste it like this in the users.txt file:
Donald;Duck;DuckyDonald;123
Mickey;Mouse;MousyMick;456
Goofy;Goof;GoofDaGoof;789

Now, the possible issues I'm seeing with this is:
If I have a set "Delimiter" and using "," when I enter several names, it will include both "," and ";" - How should I deal with that?

As to why I am asking about this, is because I don't really know Powershell well enough to know how to achieve something like this or if it even is possible? 
Now, I don't want a "solution" per se, I would rather much more enjoy a "push" in the right direction to what I could do differently. If you have any documentation I could follow, or if you have any other tips, anything is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Having users add more than one entry per inputbox will get you into trouble I think. What if a user enters 5 FirstNames, but only one LastName? Also, having users decide what delimiter to use is a bad idea IMO. Stick to creating a single 'user' on each button click, and store each as delimited line in an array. Put a second button `I'm Done` on the form and when that is clicked, output the delimited line(s) in the array to file.

Comment: @Theo Hmm, yes, that was what I was thinking as well. It might, and have brought me trouble. Being able to decide the delimiter will be removed, as I can see the issues it creates, rather than solving any! I will look into "output the delimited line(s) in the array to file" - Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, I would stick to creating a single 'user' on each button click, and store each as object in an array. 
Put a second button I'm Done on the form and when that is clicked, output to a CSV file.

<sup>(in my comment I used a self-constructed delimited string, but on second thoughts it would be best to use objects in order to create a proper CSV file)</sup>

Somewhere at the top of your code, define a script-scoped variable to collect the users

```
$script:newUsers = @()
```

Then alter the code for the $createbutton click event to

```
$createbutton.Add_Click({
    # Join the text from the various textboxes to create one row of user data
    # Assuming you would like to end up with a valid CSV file, add Objects to the array.

    # My advice is to either check if all fields actually have a value or (better)
    # disable this button untill all text fields have a value other than whitespace)
    $script:newUsers += [PsCustomObject]@{
        'FirstName'   = $firstname.Text
        'LastName'    = $lastname.Text
        'LoginName'   = $loginname.Text
        'PhoneNumber' = $phonework.Text
    }
})
```

Add a button `I'm Done` (or whatever label you give it) to the form and add a Click event handler to that:

```
$iamdonebutton.Add_Click({
    if ($script:newUsers.Count) {
        $script:newUsers | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\newUsers.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation
    }
    # you can close the form here, because the user has had enough
    $form.Close()
})
```

Hope that helps

Comment: thank you, really!
It does work indeed, and quite fluently. I just have one last query, since I am not able to figure out where and why it does this:
In my output .csv file, it includes 'FirstName','LastName','LoginName','PhoneNumber' - which is fine in general, but what it does is that it puts those variables, and every user I add between "", which generally won't work for me :/ Is there a way to "config out" the "" from the output file?

Comment: @Amne Quoting is always preferrable in a CSV file because field values may contain the chosen delimiter character or even a quote character. Without the quotes, the CSV would become mis-aligned. In your case however (the fields you are saving), you could remove the quotes safely I think. For that, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248160/9898643)