# Output file and preserve format

Tags: powershell, where-clause

this is my first time using powershell and I have a large csv file with 25 variables. I want to filter using one variable (indust) and retain the format of the original file. I tried the two commands below;

```
Get-Content  'C:\week1_industry.csv' | Select-String "Tech" |Out-File 'C:\new\week1_filtered.csv'
```

This command returns the output file including observations that don't belong to the tech industry but include the word 'tech',the variables are all grouped together but split into four lines as opposed to 25 distinct variables in the original file

```
Get-Content  'C:\week1_industry.csv' | where indust -eq "Tech" |Out-File 'C:\new\week1_filtered.csv'
```

This command does not return any results

Comment: Chances are mixing `Get-Content` with `Out-File` is messing up encoding unless you are on PowerShell Core. Please show an excerpt from the file to clearly point out what you want to accomplish. `where indust -eq "Tech"` expects there to be a property called `indust`. Reading from `Get-Content` won't produce such a property.

Comment: If your file is truly a CSV, reading with `Import-Csv` may be more beneficial. If there is a column header named `indust`, you can filter based on that name with `where`. If your row data contains longer strings, it may be better to use `-like` operator when filtering --> `where indust -like "*Tech*"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) points out, it makes sense to use [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Import-Csv) to parse your CSV file into (`[pscustomobject]`) *objects*, which allows you to filter by the values of a specific *property* (CSV column):

```
Import-Csv C:\week1_industry.csv |
  Where-Object indust -like *tech* |
    Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding Utf8 C:\new\week1_filtered.csv
```

Note:

- If you're using PowerShell *Core* (v6+), `-NoTypeInformation` isn't necessary and - assuming you want to create a UTF-8-encoded file - neither is `-Encoding Utf8`; *Windows PowerShell* (versions up to v5.1), unfortunately, default to ASCII(!) encoding.
- [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Export-Csv) defaults to *double-quoting* all field values - *invariably* so in Windows PowerShell, but you get a choice in *PowerShell [Core, v6+]* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60086908/45375).