# Remove spaces from left and right of columns in CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a use case as follows:
Excel files with thousands of rows are maintained by users, those files get converted to CSV files, then the BCP utility is used to load the data into database tables.  The trouble is the data contains spaces, sometimes at the beginning of a field, sometimes at the end, sometimes at the beginning and the end.  The data itself can legitimately contain spaces within the value.  Rather than litter the SQL code with `LTRIM(RTRIM(fieldname))` statements after the data lands in the database, because that would be extremely labor intensive, and rather than perform Excel manipulations to purge the spaces, the goal is to run a Powershell script against the CSV files to strip out the spaces at the beginning and end of each field.

Here is my experimental code so far:

file.csv

```
SpacesOnLeft,SpacesOnRight,SpacesLeftAndRight,Normal
   1,1   ,   1   ,1
        2,2         ,        2        ,2
   red clover,red clover   ,   red clover   ,red clover
```

RemoveSpaces.ps1

```
(Get-Content .\file.csv) | 
    foreach {
        $_ -replace '"\s+|\s+"','"'
    } | Out-File .\file.csv
```

The Powershell logic came from [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/3a689e30-0da7-4a13-82f4-2c17b52fba4c/remove-leading-and-trailing-space-from-csv-but-exclude-other-spaces?forum=winserverpowershell) but it doesn't modify file.csv to remove the spaces at the beginning and end of each field in the CSV file like I would expect it to do.  I'm probably missing something really simple here.  Why isn't this logic updating file.csv?

**EDIT**

Santiago Squarzon's object-oriented solution of this:

```
(Import-Csv path\to\csv.csv) | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        $property.Value = $property.Value.Trim()
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv path\to\csv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

results in this:

```
"SpacesOnLeft","SpacesOnRight","SpacesLeftAndRight","Normal"
"1","1","1","1"
"2","2","2","2"
"red clover","red clover","red clover","red clover"
```

which is very close to the desired output.  Is there a way to output the results without any double quotes?

Comment: your CSV doesnt have double-quotes so that pattern won't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object-oriented approach I would recommend would be to read your CSV using `Import-Csv` then enumerate and update each property value from each object:

```bash
(Import-Csv path\to\csv.csv) | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($property in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
        $property.Value = $property.Value.Trim()
    }
    $_
} | Export-Csv path\to\csv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

What might work for your case but I wouldn't recommend:

```bash
(Get-Content path\to\csv.csv -Raw) -replace '(?m)(^|(?<=,))\s+|\s+($|(?=,))' |
    Set-Content path\to\csv.csv
```

Regex details here: https://regex101.com/r/p4UdqO/3

Comment: The object-oriented approach generates very close to the desired output.  The only thing is, it encloses the output values in quotes.  See Edit in my original post for the output.  How can it be modified to not double quote values?

Comment: @knot22 in pwsh 7+ this is very easy, simply add `-UseQuotes Never` to `Export-Csv`. In Windows PowerShell 5.1 you will need to do something like whats shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42585263/15339544

Comment: @knot22 to be fair, the regex approach will most likely work for most cases and would be more efficient than the OO one so if you're in 5.1 mind as well test it if it works well perhaps the OO approach is not needed