# How to ensure Export-Csv is in same column order?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-core

I have the following PowerShell code that imports a csv (that has 35 column) and modifies the "Account" column. It's working as expected.  However, when I export, it's adding it as the first column when it should be the 7th position.

```
$Results = Import-Csv "$Env:FILEPATH\Metadata\Booking*.csv" | Select-Object @{Name = 'Account'; Expression = {@("A_"+$_."Account") -replace "[^0-9a-zA-z]",'_'}}, * -ExcludeProperty Account

# output to (new) csv file
$Results | Export-Csv -Path "$Env:FILEPATH\Metadata\Bookingtest.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Is there a way to preserve column order upon export? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating new objects with `Select-Object`, update the property of the object you already have:

```bash
Import-Csv "$Env:FILEPATH\Metadata\Booking*.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    # update the property
    $_.Account = 'A_' + $_.Account -replace '[^0-9a-zA-z]', '_'
    # output the updated object
    $_
} | Export-Csv -Path "$Env:FILEPATH\Metadata\Bookingtest.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

From feedback in comments, to remove quotes from your Csv in PowerShell 5.1 before exporting to a file you can use the regex pattern shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248160/15339544), the code would be:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "$Env:FILEPATH\Metadata\Booking*.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    # update the property
    $_.Account = 'A_' + $_.Account -replace '[^0-9a-zA-z]', '_'
    # output the updated object
    $_
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

$csv -replace '"([^,]*?)"(?=,|$)', '$1' |
    Set-Content -Path "$Env:FILEPATH\Metadata\Bookingtest.csv"
```

Comment: Santiago Squarzon, thank you so much, worked great! The only "issue" is it exports with all columns now in double quotes.  Do I need to pull it back in and strip double quotes or can we suppress them upon export?

Comment: @chrtak no problem, so `Export-Csv` always exports fields with double quotes `"` (normally this shouldn't be any issue, Excel shouldn't have any problem with this). If you're using a newer version of powershell (pwsh 7+) you can use `Export-Csv -UseQuotes Never` to avoid quotes. in powershell 5.1 the only way around it is to use `ConvertTo-Csv` then remove the quotes via replacement and lastly `Set-Content` to export to a file.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was not as easy as I thought  :) do you have an example of the convert, replacement and then set content?

Comment: @chrtak see the update